# how to do time taking computation using javascript without getting page unresposive error

Tags: javascript, wordle-game

Aim is to obtain best guess for wordle.
I have tried to give most relevant part of my code.
Please allow me to explain.
Here we have solution_dict array which contains all wordle solutions.
There is history_words array which contain all wordle solutions of past.
My purpose is to choose a word from solution_dict that is most helpful.
I create an array called new_solutions_list that contains wordle solutions in future so it is equal to solution_dict  - history_words .
Now I do following for each word (say x) in solution_dict
(1)Compare x with every word in new_solutions_list and get a string output containing 5 letters using y(yellow) , g(green) and b(black). 
Most of you may be aware that if guess letter matches with solution and is in correct spot then it becomes green , if guess letter is not in solution then it is shown black and if guess letter is present in solution but not at that place then it is shown yellow (there is little complexity if solution has guess letter m times and guess letter appears n times with n>m then at some places we will get yellow and at others black)
(2)Suppose new_solutions_list length is 1645 (2311-666).
So I have an array of length 1645 whose each element is a 5 letter string . In this array , suppose 'y' strings are unique then our word 'x' can differentiate 'y' words.
(3)So i add to guess_table all conflict words and their count.

We will choose word that has minimum conflicts . Please note that I have not sorted table because it is not relevant here.
The code I have shown here takes 8 minutes if you run it with dev tools enabled . Otherwise after few seconds you will get message 'page unresponsive - wait or exit'.

Is there any way I can avoid page unresposive without selecting devtools in browser ?

Thanks for listening.

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>wordle solver helper</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="findbestamongsolutions()">Give best guess</button>
        <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" id="notelog"> </textarea>
        <p id="user_request_logs" style="word-break: break-all;"></p>
        <script>
            const solution_dict=["snafu","guano","cigar","rebut","sissy","humph","awake","blush","focal","evade","naval","serve","heath","dwarf","model","karma","stink","grade","quiet","bench","abate","feign","major","death","fresh","crust","stool","colon","abase","marry","react","batty","pride","floss","helix","croak","staff","paper","unfed","whelp","trawl","outdo","adobe","crazy","sower","repay","digit","crate","cluck","spike","mimic","pound","maxim","linen","unmet","flesh","booby","forth","first","stand","belly","ivory","seedy","print","yearn","drain","bribe","stout","panel","crass","flume","offal","agree","error","swirl","argue","bleed","delta","flick","totem","wooer","front","shrub","parry","biome","lapel","start","greet","goner","golem","lusty","loopy","round","audit","lying","gamma","labor","islet","civic","forge","corny","moult","basic","salad","agate","spicy","spray","essay","fjord","spend","kebab","guild","aback","motor","alone","hatch","hyper","thumb","dowry","ought","belch","dutch","pilot","tweed","comet","jaunt","enema","steed","abyss","growl","fling","dozen","boozy","erode","world","gouge","click","briar","great","altar","pulpy","blurt","coast","duchy","groin","fixer","group","rogue","badly","smart","pithy","gaudy","chill","heron","vodka","finer","surer","radio","rouge","perch","retch","wrote","clock","tilde","store","prove","bring","solve","cheat","grime","exult","usher","epoch","triad","break","rhino","viral","conic","masse","sonic","vital","trace","using","peach","champ","baton","brake","pluck","craze","gripe","weary","picky","acute","ferry","aside","tapir","troll","unify","rebus","boost","truss","siege","tiger","banal","slump","crank","gorge","query","drink","favor","abbey","tangy","panic","solar","shire","proxy","point","robot","prick","wince","crimp","knoll","sugar","whack","mount","perky","could","wrung","light","those","moist","shard","pleat","aloft","skill","elder","frame","humor","pause","ulcer","ultra","robin","cynic","aroma","caulk","shake","dodge","swill","tacit","other","thorn","trove","bloke","vivid","spill","chant","choke","rupee","nasty","mourn","ahead","brine","cloth","hoard","sweet","month","lapse","watch","today","focus","smelt","tease","cater","movie","saute","allow","renew","their","slosh","purge","chest","depot","epoxy","nymph","found","shall","stove","lowly","snout","trope","fewer","shawl","natal","comma","foray","scare","stair","black","squad","royal","chunk","mince","shame","cheek","ample","flair","foyer","cargo","oxide","plant","olive","inert","askew","heist","shown","zesty","trash","larva","forgo","story","hairy","train","homer","badge","midst","canny","shine","gecko","farce","slung","tipsy","metal","yield","delve","being","scour","glass","gamer","scrap","money","hinge","album","vouch","asset","tiara","crept","bayou","atoll","manor","creak","showy","phase","froth","depth","gloom","flood","trait","girth","piety","goose","float","donor","atone","primo","apron","blown","cacao","loser","input","gloat","awful","brink","smite","beady","rusty","retro","droll","gawky","hutch","pinto","egret","lilac","sever","field","fluff","agape","voice","stead","berth","madam","night","bland","liver","wedge","roomy","wacky","flock","angry","trite","aphid","tryst","midge","power","elope","cinch","motto","stomp","upset","bluff","cramp","quart","coyly","youth","rhyme","buggy","alien","smear","unfit","patty","cling","glean","label","hunky","khaki","poker","gruel","twice","twang","shrug","treat","waste","merit","woven","needy","clown","irony","ruder","gauze","chief","onset","prize","fungi","charm","gully","inter","whoop","taunt","leery","class","theme","lofty","tibia","booze","alpha","thyme","doubt","parer","chute","stick","trice","alike","recap","saint","glory","grate","admit","brisk","soggy","usurp","scald","scorn","leave","twine","sting","bough","marsh","sloth","dandy","vigor","howdy","enjoy","valid","ionic","equal","floor","catch","spade","stein","exist","quirk","denim","grove","spiel","mummy","fault","foggy","flout","carry","sneak","libel","waltz","aptly","piney","inept","aloud","photo","dream","stale","unite","snarl","baker","there","glyph","pooch","hippy","spell","folly","louse","gulch","vault","godly","threw","fleet","grave","inane","shock","crave","spite","valve","skimp","claim","rainy","musty","pique","daddy","quasi","arise","aging","valet","opium","avert","stuck","recut","mulch","genre","plume","rifle","count","incur","total","wrest","mocha","deter","study","lover","safer","rivet","funny","smoke","mound","undue","sedan","pagan","swine","guile","gusty","equip","tough","canoe","chaos","covet","human","udder","lunch","blast","stray","manga","melee","lefty","quick","paste","given","octet","risen","groan","leaky","grind","carve","loose","sadly","spilt","apple","slack","honey","final","sheen","eerie","minty","slick","derby","wharf","spelt","coach","erupt","singe","price","spawn","fairy","jiffy","filmy","stack","chose","sleep","ardor","nanny","niece","woozy","handy","grace","ditto","stank","cream","usual","diode","valor","angle","ninja","muddy","chase","reply","prone","spoil","heart","shade","diner","arson","onion","sleet","dowel","couch","palsy","bowel","smile","evoke","creek","lance","eagle","idiot","siren","built","embed","award","dross","annul","goody","frown","patio","laden","humid","elite","lymph","edify","might","reset","visit","gusto","purse","vapor","crock","write","sunny","loath","chaff","slide","queer","venom","stamp","sorry","still","acorn","aping","pushy","tamer","hater","mania","awoke","brawn","swift","exile","birch","lucky","freer","risky","ghost","plier","lunar","winch","snare","nurse","house","borax","nicer","lurch","exalt","about","savvy","toxin","tunic","pried","inlay","chump","lanky","cress","eater","elude","cycle","kitty","boule","moron","tenet","place","lobby","plush","vigil","index","blink","clung","qualm","croup","clink","juicy","stage","decay","nerve","flier","shaft","crook","clean","china","ridge","vowel","gnome","snuck","icing","spiny","rigor","snail","flown","rabid","prose","thank","poppy","budge","fiber","moldy","dowdy","kneel","track","caddy","quell","dumpy","paler","swore","rebar","scuba","splat","flyer","horny","mason","doing","ozone","amply","molar","ovary","beset","queue","cliff","magic","truce","sport","fritz","edict","twirl","verse","llama","eaten","range","whisk","hovel","rehab","macaw","sigma","spout","verve","sushi","dying","fetid","brain","buddy","thump","scion","candy","chord","basin","march","crowd","arbor","gayly","musky","stain","dally","bless","bravo","stung","title","ruler","kiosk","blond","ennui","layer","fluid","tatty","score","cutie","zebra","barge","matey","bluer","aider","shook","river","privy","betel","frisk","bongo","begun","azure","weave","genie","sound","glove","braid","scope","wryly","rover","assay","ocean","bloom","irate","later","woken","silky","wreck","dwelt","slate","smack","solid","amaze","hazel","wrist","jolly","globe","flint","rouse","civil","vista","relax","cover","alive","beech","jetty","bliss","vocal","often","dolly","eight","joker","since","event","ensue","shunt","diver","poser","worst","sweep","alley","creed","anime","leafy","bosom","dunce","stare","pudgy","waive","choir","stood","spoke","outgo","delay","bilge","ideal","clasp","seize","hotly","laugh","sieve","block","meant","grape","noose","hardy","shied","drawl","daisy","putty","strut","burnt","tulip","crick","idyll","vixen","furor","geeky","cough","naive","shoal","stork","bathe","aunty","check","prime","brass","outer","furry","razor","elect","evict","imply","demur","quota","haven","cavil","swear","crump","dough","gavel","wagon","salon","nudge","harem","pitch","sworn","pupil","excel","stony","cabin","unzip","queen","trout","polyp","earth","storm","until","taper","enter","child","adopt","minor","fatty","husky","brave","filet","slime","glint","tread","steal","regal","guest","every","murky","share","spore","hoist","buxom","inner","otter","dimly","level","sumac","donut","stilt","arena","sheet","scrub","fancy","slimy","pearl","silly","porch","dingo","sepia","amble","shady","bread","friar","reign","dairy","quill","cross","brood","tuber","shear","posit","blank","villa","shank","piggy","freak","which","among","fecal","shell","would","algae","large","rabbi","agony","amuse","bushy","copse","swoon","knife","pouch","ascot","plane","crown","urban","snide","relay","abide","viola","rajah","straw","dilly","crash","amass","third","trick","tutor","woody","blurb","grief","disco","where","sassy","beach","sauna","comic","clued","creep","caste","graze","snuff","frock","gonad","drunk","prong","lurid","steel","halve","buyer","vinyl","utile","smell","adage","worry","tasty","local","trade","finch","ashen","modal","gaunt","clove","enact","adorn","roast","speck","sheik","missy","grunt","snoop","party","touch","mafia","emcee","array","south","vapid","jelly","skulk","angst","tubal","lower","crest","sweat","cyber","adore","tardy","swami","notch","groom","roach","hitch","young","align","ready","frond","strap","puree","realm","venue","swarm","offer","seven","dryer","diary","dryly","drank","acrid","heady","theta","junto","pixie","quoth","bonus","shalt","penne","amend","datum","build","piano","shelf","lodge","suing","rearm","coral","ramen","worth","psalm","infer","overt","mayor","ovoid","glide","usage","poise","randy","chuck","prank","fishy","tooth","ether","drove","idler","swath","stint","while","begat","apply","slang","tarot","radar","credo","aware","canon","shift","timer","bylaw","serum","three","steak","iliac","shirk","blunt","puppy","penal","joist","bunny","shape","beget","wheel","adept","stunt","stole","topaz","chore","fluke","afoot","bloat","bully","dense","caper","sneer","boxer","jumbo","lunge","space","avail","short","slurp","loyal","flirt","pizza","conch","tempo","droop","plate","bible","plunk","afoul","savoy","steep","agile","stake","dwell","knave","beard","arose","motif","smash","broil","glare","shove","baggy","mammy","swamp","along","rugby","wager","quack","squat","snaky","debit","mange","skate","ninth","joust","tramp","spurn","medal","micro","rebel","flank","learn","nadir","maple","comfy","remit","gruff","ester","least","mogul","fetch","cause","oaken","aglow","meaty","gaffe","shyly","racer","prowl","thief","stern","poesy","rocky","tweet","waist","spire","grope","havoc","patsy","truly","forty","deity","uncle","swish","giver","preen","bevel","lemur","draft","slope","annoy","lingo","bleak","ditty","curly","cedar","dirge","grown","horde","drool","shuck","crypt","cumin","stock","gravy","locus","wider","breed","quite","chafe","cache","blimp","deign","fiend","logic","cheap","elide","rigid","false","renal","pence","rowdy","shoot","blaze","envoy","posse","brief","never","abort","mouse","mucky","sulky","fiery","media","trunk","yeast","clear","skunk","scalp","bitty","cider","koala","duvet","segue","creme","super","grill","after","owner","ember","reach","nobly","empty","speed","gipsy","recur","smock","dread","merge","burst","kappa","amity","shaky","hover","carol","snort","synod","faint","haunt","flour","chair","detox","shrew","tense","plied","quark","burly","novel","waxen","stoic","jerky","blitz","beefy","lyric","hussy","towel","quilt","below","bingo","wispy","brash","scone","toast","easel","saucy","value","spice","honor","route","sharp","bawdy","radii","skull","phony","issue","lager","swell","urine","gassy","trial","flora","upper","latch","wight","brick","retry","holly","decal","grass","shack","dogma","mover","defer","sober","optic","crier","vying","nomad","flute","hippo","shark","drier","obese","bugle","tawny","chalk","feast","ruddy","pedal","scarf","cruel","bleat","tidal","slush","semen","windy","dusty","sally","igloo","nerdy","jewel","shone","whale","hymen","abuse","fugue","elbow","crumb","pansy","welsh","syrup","terse","suave","gamut","swung","drake","freed","afire","shirt","grout","oddly","tithe","plaid","dummy","broom","blind","torch","enemy","again","tying","pesky","alter","gazer","noble","ethos","bride","extol","decor","hobby","beast","idiom","utter","these","sixth","alarm","erase","elegy","spunk","piper","scaly","scold","hefty","chick","sooty","canal","whiny","slash","quake","joint","swept","prude","heavy","wield","femme","lasso","maize","shale","screw","spree","smoky","whiff","scent","glade","spent","prism","stoke","riper","orbit","cocoa","guilt","humus","shush","table","smirk","wrong","noisy","alert","shiny","elate","resin","whole","hunch","pixel","polar","hotel","sword","cleat","mango","rumba","puffy","filly","billy","leash","clout","dance","ovate","facet","chili","paint","liner","curio","salty","audio","snake","fable","cloak","navel","spurt","pesto","balmy","flash","unwed","early","churn","weedy","stump","lease","witty","wimpy","spoof","saner","blend","salsa","thick","warty","manic","blare","squib","spoon","probe","crepe","knack","force","debut","order","haste","teeth","agent","widen","icily","slice","ingot","clash","juror","blood","abode","throw","unity","pivot","slept","troop","spare","sewer","parse","morph","cacti","tacky","spool","demon","moody","annex","begin","fuzzy","patch","water","lumpy","admin","omega","limit","tabby","macho","aisle","skiff","basis","plank","verge","botch","crawl","lousy","slain","cubic","raise","wrack","guide","foist","cameo","under","actor","revue","fraud","harpy","scoop","climb","refer","olden","clerk","debar","tally","ethic","cairn","tulle","ghoul","hilly","crude","apart","scale","older","plain","sperm","briny","abbot","rerun","quest","crisp","bound","befit","drawn","suite","itchy","cheer","bagel","guess","broad","axiom","chard","caput","leant","harsh","curse","proud","swing","opine","taste","lupus","gumbo","miner","green","chasm","lipid","topic","armor","brush","crane","mural","abled","habit","bossy","maker","dusky","dizzy","lithe","brook","jazzy","fifty","sense","giant","surly","legal","fatal","flunk","began","prune","small","slant","scoff","torus","ninny","covey","viper","taken","moral","vogue","owing","token","entry","booth","voter","chide","elfin","ebony","neigh","minim","melon","kneed","decoy","voila","ankle","arrow","mushy","tribe","cease","eager","birth","graph","odder","terra","weird","tried","clack","color","rough","weigh","uncut","ladle","strip","craft","minus","dicey","titan","lucid","vicar","dress","ditch","gypsy","pasta","taffy","flame","swoop","aloof","sight","broke","teary","chart","sixty","wordy","sheer","leper","nosey","bulge","savor","clamp","funky","foamy","toxic","brand","plumb","dingy","butte","drill","tripe","bicep","tenor","krill","worse","drama","hyena","think","ratio","cobra","basil","scrum","bused","phone","court","camel","proof","heard","angel","petal","pouty","throb","maybe","fetal","sprig","spine","shout","cadet","macro","dodgy","satyr","rarer","binge","trend","nutty","leapt","amiss","split","myrrh","width","sonar","tower","baron","fever","waver","spark","belie","sloop","expel","smote","baler","above","north","wafer","scant","frill","awash","snack","scowl","frail","drift","limbo","fence","motel","ounce","wreak","revel","talon","prior","knelt","cello","flake","debug","anode","crime","salve","scout","imbue","pinky","stave","vague","chock","fight","video","stone","teach","cleft","frost","prawn","booty","twist","apnea","stiff","plaza","ledge","tweak","board","grant","medic","bacon","cable","brawl","slunk","raspy","forum","drone","women","mucus","boast","toddy","coven","tumor","truer","wrath","stall","steam","axial","purer","daily","trail","niche","mealy","juice","nylon","plump","merry","flail","papal","wheat","berry","cower","erect","brute","leggy","snipe","sinew","skier","penny","jumpy","rally","umbra","scary","modem","gross","avian","greed","satin","tonic","parka","sniff","livid","stark","trump","giddy","reuse","taboo","avoid","quote","devil","liken","gloss","gayer","beret","noise","gland","dealt","sling","rumor","opera","thigh","tonga","flare","wound","white","bulky","etude","horse","circa","paddy","inbox","fizzy","grain","exert","surge","gleam","belle","salvo","crush","fruit","sappy","taker","tract","ovine","spiky","frank","reedy","filth","spasm","heave","mambo","right","clank","trust","lumen","borne","spook","sauce","amber","lathe","carat","corer","dirty","slyly","affix","alloy","taint","sheep","kinky","wooly","mauve","flung","yacht","fried","quail","brunt","grimy","curvy","cagey","rinse","deuce","state","grasp","milky","bison","graft","sandy","baste","flask","hedge","girly","swash","boney","coupe","endow","abhor","welch","blade","tight","geese","miser","mirth","cloud","cabal","leech","close","tenth","pecan","droit","grail","clone","guise","ralph","tango","biddy","smith","mower","payee","serif","drape","fifth","spank","glaze","allot","truck","kayak","virus","testy","tepee","fully","zonal","metro","curry","grand","banjo","axion","bezel","occur","chain","nasal","gooey","filer","brace","allay","pubic","raven","plead","gnash","flaky","munch","dully","eking","thing","slink","hurry","theft","shorn","pygmy","ranch","wring","lemon","shore","mamma","froze","newer","style","moose","antic","drown","vegan","chess","guppy","union","lever","lorry","image","cabby","druid","exact","truth","dopey","spear","cried","chime","crony","stunk","timid","batch","gauge","rotor","crack","curve","latte","witch","bunch","repel","anvil","soapy","meter","broth","madly","dried","scene","known","magma","roost","woman","thong","punch","pasty","downy","knead","whirl","rapid","clang","anger","drive","goofy","email","music","stuff","bleep","rider","mecca","folio","setup","verso","quash","fauna","gummy","happy","newly","fussy","relic","guava","ratty","fudge","femur","chirp","forte","alibi","whine","petty","golly","plait","fleck","felon","gourd","brown","thrum","ficus","stash","decry","wiser","junta","visor","daunt","scree","impel","await","press","whose","turbo","stoop","speak","mangy","eying","inlet","crone","pulse","mossy","staid","hence","pinch","teddy","sully","snore","ripen","snowy","attic","going","leach","mouth","hound","clump","tonal","bigot","peril","piece","blame","haute","spied","undid","intro","basal","rodeo","guard","steer","loamy","scamp","scram","manly","hello","vaunt","organ","feral","knock","extra","condo","adapt","willy","polka","rayon","skirt","faith","torso","match","mercy","tepid","sleek","riser","twixt","peace","flush","catty","login","eject","roger","rival","untie","refit","aorta","adult","judge","rower","artsy","rural","shave","bobby","eclat","fella","gaily","harry","hasty","hydro","liege","octal","ombre","payer","sooth","unset","unlit","vomit","fanny","fetus","butch","stalk","flack","widow","augur"];
            const history_words=["agony","thief","carat","borax","qualm","under","snafu","ledge","locus","leafy","smash","ratio","flora","stock","march","every","bread","beset","hurry","guano","untie","voter","grout","staid","duvet","tough","glove","credo","yacht","mealy","cider","sweep","surly","blame","birth","email","revel","where","regal","horse","pinky","toxic","trend","squat","above","moose","polka","worse","syrup","fifty","arbor","vague","riper","ruddy","sweat","kiosk","avail","cache","magic","salsa","sound","usage","giant","debug","heady","stage","flail","apple","ninth","dance","unlit","tasty","shirk","scold","cross","crave","fishy","flirt","taper","slate","third","lunar","excel","aorta","poise","extra","judge","condo","impel","havoc","molar","manly","whine","skirt","antic","layer","sleek","belie","lemon","opera","pixie","grimy","sedan","leapt","human","koala","spire","frock","adopt","chard","mucky","alter","blurb","matey","elude","count","maize","beefy","worry","chord","probe","rival","usual","spoke","apply","naive","knock","braid","infer","joust","amber","woken","adore","torso","chafe","eject","study","undue","tepid","happy","clean","itchy","feast","drive","prime","axiom","brave","avert","glyph","there","baker","snarl","maple","inane","valet","medal","unite","rainy","spell","begin","stale","dream","photo","aloud","inept","piney","aptly","waltz","libel","sneak","carry","flout","foggy","fault","mummy","spiel","grove","denim","quirk","exist","stein","spade","catch","floor","equal","ionic","valid","enjoy","howdy","vigor","dandy","sloth","marsh","bough","sting","twine","leave","scorn","scald","usurp","soggy","brisk","admit","grate","glory","saint","recap","alike","trice","stick","chute","parer","doubt","thyme","alpha","booze","tibia","lofty","theme","class","leery","taunt","whoop","inter","gully","charm","fungi","prize","onset","chief","gauze","ruder","irony","clown","needy","woven","merit","treat","waste","shrug","twang","twice","gruel","poker","khaki","hunky","label","glean","cling","patty","unfit","smear","alien","buggy","rhyme","youth","coyly","quart","cramp","bluff","upset","stomp","motto","cinch","elope","power","midge","tryst","aphid","trite","angry","flock","wacky","roomy","wedge","liver","bland","night","madam","berth","stead","voice","agape","fluff","field","sever","lilac","egret","pinto","hutch","gawky","droll","retro","rusty","beady","smite","brink","awful","gloat","input","loser","cacao","blown","apron","primo","atone","donor","float","goose","piety","girth","trait","flood","gloom","depth","froth","phase","showy","creak","manor","atoll","bayou","crept","tiara","asset","vouch","album","hinge","money","scrap","gamer","glass","scour","being","delve","yield","metal","tipsy","slung","farce","gecko","shine","canny","midst","badge","homer","train","hairy","story","forgo","larva","trash","zesty","shown","heist","askew","inert","olive","plant","oxide","cargo","foyer","flair","ample","cheek","shame","mince","chunk","royal","squad","black","stair","scare","foray","comma","natal","shawl","fewer","trope","snout","lowly","stove","shall","found","nymph","epoxy","depot","chest","purge","slosh","their","renew","allow","saute","movie","cater","tease","smelt","focus","today","watch","lapse","month","sweet","hoard","cloth","brine","ahead","mourn","nasty","rupee","choke","chant","spill","vivid","bloke","trove","thorn","other","tacit","swill","dodge","shake","caulk","aroma","cynic","robin","ultra","ulcer","pause","humor","frame","elder","skill","aloft","pleat","shard","moist","those","light","wrung","could","perky","mount","whack","sugar","knoll","crimp","wince","prick","robot","point","proxy","shire","solar","panic","tangy","abbey","favor","drink","query","gorge","crank","slump","banal","tiger","siege","truss","boost","rebus","unify","troll","tapir","aside","ferry","acute","picky","weary","gripe","craze","pluck","brake","baton","champ","peach","using","trace","vital","sonic","masse","conic","viral","rhino","break","triad","epoch","usher","exult","grime","cheat","solve","bring","prove","store","tilde","clock","wrote","retch","perch","rouge","radio","surer","finer","vodka","heron","chill","gaudy","pithy","smart","badly","rogue","group","fixer","groin","duchy","coast","blurt","pulpy","altar","great","briar","click","gouge","world","erode","boozy","dozen","fling","growl","abyss","steed","enema","jaunt","comet","tweed","pilot","dutch","belch","ought","dowry","thumb","hyper","hatch","alone","motor","aback","guild","kebab","spend","fjord","essay","spray","spicy","agate","salad","basic","moult","corny","forge","civic","islet","labor","gamma","lying","audit","round","loopy","lusty","golem","goner","greet","start","lapel","biome","parry","shrub","front","wooer","totem","flick","delta","bleed","argue","swirl","error","agree","offal","flume","crass","panel","stout","bribe","drain","yearn","print","seedy","ivory","belly","stand","first","forth","booby","flesh","unmet","linen","maxim","pound","mimic","spike","cluck","crate","digit","repay","sower","crazy","adobe","outdo","trawl","whelp","unfed","paper","staff","croak","helix","floss","pride","batty","react","marry","abase","colon","stool","crust","fresh","death","major","feign","abate","bench","quiet","grade","stink","karma","model","dwarf","heath","serve","naval","evade","focal","blush","awake","humph","sissy","rebut","cigar"];
            function findbestamongsolutions()
            {   const started = new Date();
                var currtime = String(started.getHours())+':'+String(started.getMinutes())+':'+String(started.getSeconds());
                document.getElementById("notelog").innerHTML="started at "+currtime;
                    console.log("started at "+currtime);
                var new_solutions_list=[];
                var string_log='';
                for (var i = 0; i <solution_dict.length ; i++)
                {   if( !(history_words.includes(solution_dict[i])) )
                        new_solutions_list.push(solution_dict[i]);
                }
                document.getElementById("user_request_logs").innerHTML = '<table id="guess_table"></table>';
                for (var i = 0; i <solution_dict.length ; i++)
                {   
                    var diffscorearray=[];
                    var troublesomewords=[];
                    for (var j = 0; j <new_solutions_list.length ; j++)
                    {   var diffscore=getstringdiffscore(new_solutions_list[j],solution_dict[i]);
                        diffscorearray.push(diffscore);
                    }
                    for (let k = 0; k < diffscorearray.length; k++)
                    {   arraywithoutcurrele = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(diffscorearray));
                        arraywithoutcurrele.splice(k,1);
                        if(arraywithoutcurrele.includes(diffscorearray[k]))
                        {
                            troublesomewords.push(new_solutions_list[k]);
                        }
                    }
                    addtotable(solution_dict[i],troublesomewords.length,troublesomewords);
                }
                const end = new Date();
                var currtime = String(end.getHours())+':'+String(end.getMinutes())+':'+String(end.getSeconds());
                document.getElementById("notelog").innerHTML=document.getElementById("notelog").innerHTML+'\n'+"ended at "+currtime;
                console.log("ended at "+currtime);
            }

            function addtotable(word,troublecount,troubledata)
            {   var mytable=document.getElementById("guess_table");
                var rowCount = mytable.rows.length+1;
                var row = mytable.insertRow(rowCount-1).outerHTML="<tr id='row" + String(rowCount) + "'><td nowrap>" + '(' + String(rowCount) + ')' + "</td><td nowrap>" + String(word) + "-" + String(troublecount) + "</td><td>" + String(troubledata) +"</td></tr>";
            }

            function getstringdiffscore(word_in_guess_list,trial_word_to_consider)
            {   var diffstring='';
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
                {   var letter_under_consideration=trial_word_to_consider.charAt(i);
                    if(word_in_guess_list.charAt(i)==letter_under_consideration)
                    {   diffstring=diffstring.concat('g');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(!(word_in_guess_list.includes(letter_under_consideration)))
                            diffstring=diffstring.concat('b');
                        else
                        {   var count_of_letter_in_guess_list=word_in_guess_list.split(letter_under_consideration).length;
                            var count_of_letter_in_trial_word=trial_word_to_consider.split(letter_under_consideration).length;
                            if(count_of_letter_in_guess_list>=count_of_letter_in_trial_word)
                                diffstring=diffstring.concat('y');
                            else
                            {   var substring_of_trial_word=trial_word_to_consider.substr(0,i);
                                var count_of_letter_in_trial_word_substring=substring_of_trial_word.split(letter_under_consideration).length;
                                if(count_of_letter_in_trial_word_substring<=count_of_letter_in_guess_list)
                                    diffstring=diffstring.concat('y');
                                else
                                    diffstring=diffstring.concat('b');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return diffstring;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can save it and as html file and try it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload these tasks to a Worker Thread using the [Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker?retiredLocale=de). This will spawn a new thread and keep the main one unoccupied.

However if you string matching takes 8 minutes there must be something wrong with your code. Try solving the performance issue first, before bandaiding it with a worker thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply . i can do little performance improvement by stopping comparisons if conflict count exceeds smallest known count . still , the nature of problem involves lot of computation . Can you give a sample code about offloading assuming i pass two string arrays to worker thread and it returns an array of answers ?